# Could plone put JavaScript at bottom?

Tags: javascript, plone

Yslow suggest javascript should be putted at bottom. However, all system javascript of Plone are putted in head.
Could we put js at bottom in plone?

Answer (score 2):

Likely doable by moving the viewlet managers to the bottom of the main_template. I would not expect and significant impact. There are dozens of other screws influencing the performance of a site...just one out of many. If your page rendering times goes down from 500ms to 450ms...who cares? Nobody will notice this.

Comment: That would be 10% decrease in the page rendering time. There are use cases where such optimization is worth the cost. I suggest that maybe CMFPlone generally would consider this approach instead of current <head> linking. Also the scripts could be declared as asynchronously if there are no dependencies between them,

Comment: From a conversation I had with @limi in #plone this javascripts at bottom thing is a myth. <davi-lima> For better UI performance, it is sometimes recommended to move all javascript to the bottom of the page. Does anyone know why Plone doesn't do it?
< limi > davi-lima: the "put all JS at the bottom" is mostly a myth these days
< limi > with modern browsers, that is
< limi > I'm sure it still helps on IE6 ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google analytics slot in the control panel. It will render your script at bottom. Don't expect to load tons of code,  though. To do this you have to create a new viewlet through code.

Comment: First ,we create a new viewlet and embed it to bottom of document.secondly we may patch Products.ResourceRegistries in order to register all js too the customize viewlet. Is OK?

Comment: Whoa...  Wait...  If you are creating and new viewlet to wrap all "yours" javascript you don't have to touch resource registries. You call your javascript from the viewlet and you're done. Do you want to move down all plone javascript stuffs? in this case you'd better customize main_template.pt moving the javascript viewlet manager where you want and keep using resource registry as alwais.